# Django. How do I pass the next variable to auth_views.login

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-authentication

this is kind of simple but I'm having trouble finding the correct format:

How can I pass the `next` variable to `auth_views.login`?

This is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name="login"),
```

How can I pass the `next` variable to the view, so it doesn't redirect to the default *`/accounts/profile/`* ?

I tried this:

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'extra_context': {'next': '/'}}, name="login"),
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Won't adding `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in the settings file work?

Comment: Yes, but on the docs it writes `If next isn’t provided, it redirects to settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` ... I need to "provide next".

Comment: right. so why not change the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` hence it will redirect where you need to without any custom parameters in views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `next` parameter as a query parameter in the page where you are submitting login data via `POST`.

Lets say you have a form in the login template, then you can specify `next` by something like:

```
<form action="<login_url>?next=/my/next/url/" method="POST">
```